# ajax InvalidCharacterError

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm not familiar with ajax and I'm debugging in IE10 and got an error **InvalidCharacterError** on this block of code. When I set it to the **edge mode** it throws an **Invalid Argument Error** .

```
jQuery.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: ({copyEventId : copyEventId}),
    success: function(data){
        $j('#Tab1').html(data);
        initializeWizardState();
        bindQuestionFieldEvents(1);
    },
    error: function(xmlHttpResponse, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('ERROR!! status: ' + textStatus);
    },
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: Try turning on `async` as sync ajax is deprecated

Comment: @Justinas this worked. It's throwing an error with my dialog box. Don't think it's related but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Justinas suggested. Setting async to true fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
jQuery.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {"copyEventId" : copyEventId},
    success: function(data){
        $j('#Tab1').html(data);
        initializeWizardState();
        bindQuestionFieldEvents(1);
    },
    error: function(xmlHttpResponse, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('ERROR!! status: ' + textStatus);
    },
    cache: false
});
```